# How to use ComposeUIViewController in KMM kotlin

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I try to learn MVI and KMM so I have started a Simple Project
But when I want to use `ComposeUIViewController` this Error apears :

```
fun MainViewController() = ComposeUIViewController {
    App(
        darkTheme = false,
        dynamicColor = false
    )
}
```

this Error appears:

```
Cannot access class 'platform.UIKit.UIViewController'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

My OS is windows 10 but I searched a lot and everywhere wrote I can use KMM on Windows

Comment: you can't develop iOS/Mac apps from windows, you need macos for that